# How to implement delete api call

Tags: java, api, servlets

Currently I am implementing API calls using Servlet.

- Whenever there is a call to fetch data, I use doGet() (GET request).
- To put data I use doPost() (POST request).

From reading the references, I got the idea to use `POST` whenever you change the database, and `GET` is simply for fetching the data.

I need to implement a call to delete an item from the database. Should I implement this with `POST` or `GET`?

Comment: Use doDelete if it means deletion, there's nothing wrong with that. People don't usually use doDelete as browsers are not capable of sending doDelete requests, but as you're building an API your client most likely allows for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use `doPost(..)`. If you are making a REST API you can consider `doDelete(..)`